# Changing ImageView position based on angle of rotation

Tags: java, animation, javafx, 2d, game-development

I am trying to make an `ImageView` change its position based on the direction it is facing.

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Demo extends Application {

    public void start(Stage window) {
        window.setTitle("Changing ImageView position based on angle of rotation");

        int speed = 10; // You can modify the speed here

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTBJoRKh1UKimWTSLdabW2b8RSLDeSgMfSqqg&usqp=CAU"));
        imageView.setX(100);
        imageView.setY(100);

        imageView.setRotate(65); // This is where you can change the angle of rotation

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        window.setScene(scene);

        final long[] lastNanoTime = {System.nanoTime()};

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long currentTime) {
                double elapsedTime = (currentTime - lastNanoTime[0]) / 1000000000.0;
                lastNanoTime[0] = currentTime;

                imageView.setX(imageView.getX() + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(imageView.getRotate())) * speed * elapsedTime);
                imageView.setY(imageView.getY() + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(imageView.getRotate())) * speed * elapsedTime);

            }
        }.start();

        window.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The above code is based on the code I am using. You can adjust the degrees accordingly to see the issue. The `ImageView` does not move in the direction it is facing. Note: I found a random .png file online for the purpose of this demo. You can substitute with a different image in you own code in order to better visualize the problem.

The issue is, the `ImageView` does not move in the direction it is facing. When oriented vertically (0° or 180°) the `ImageView` moves backward, but when oriented horizontally (90° or 270°) it moves straight ahead like it should. When oriented diagonally, it moves somewhere in between.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please post [mre]

Comment: It certainly does. +1. I assume you want the rocket to always move to the direction its tip is pointing to, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction of the `y` axis is down. So when the angle is 0 and you increase `y` value you'll get down movement. 
To make the image move up when the angle is 0 simplט change the increment sign from: 
`imageView.setY(imageView.getY() + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(imageView.getRotate())) * speed * elapsedTime);`

to 
`imageView.setY(imageView.getY() - Math.cos(Math.toRadians(imageView.getRotate())) * speed * elapsedTime);`

so angle of 0 should move the image up, 90 right, 180 down and so on.